# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match') at getLocalIdent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

i'm trying to make build script. so i can build with webpack it kinda like this
`build.server.js`

```
    process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'production';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
 
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    throw err;
});
 
require('../config/env');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('../config/webpack.config.server');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
 
function build() {
    console.log('Creating server build');
    fs.emptyDirSync(paths.ssrBuild);
    let compiler = webpack(config);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        compiler.run((err, status) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(status.toString());
        });
    });
}
 
build();
```

after i code this and  type `node scripts/build.server.js` , this error comes out.

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')    
    at getLocalIdent (C:\Users\jhs00\OneDrive\바탕 화면\공부자료\ssrProject\ssrproject\node_modules\react-dev-utils\getCSSModuleLocalIdent.js:20:49)
```

getLoslIdent is in here (webpack.config.server.js)

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const webpack = require('webpack');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
...
```

i searched similar question and tried delete `package-lock.json`, node_modules and reinstall it. but didn't work. what should i do?